# Can you select role which gives you money but you can't use it in Puerto Rico?

Tags: puerto-rico

I have a situation where a player chooses the Trader because it has 5 coins even though he has nothing to sell in the trading house. Can he do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Taken from the rules:

> Implementing the action of a character is voluntary (exception: Captain)

Note: You can still choose Captain if you have no goods, the exception just means that if you pull Captain and have goods, you have to ship.

Comment: this does not mean that you can't pick captain if you have no good

Comment: Just to clarify even further, the other players get a chance to take the action of the role you choose, even if you elect not to.

Answer (score 3):

### Definitely

Choosing a role merely for it's privilege is a perfectly valid move. It may not always be wise to choose a role you cannot fully take advantage of but if you are really short on cash such a trade off may be warranted...

Comment: as an addendum:  This is also a good way to screw with your opponents.